# How to call a service from console Application in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have service "http://deveqtradedb.lazard.com/API.aspx?action=export&entity=global"

I want to call this service from Main() function of console application

Comment: It's good that you know what you want to do.  But what's your question?

Comment: Your link isn't working. And it would be helpfull to get more information. What have you tried already and what type of service do you want to call?

Comment: what makes you think calling it from a console app is any different?

Comment: want to get the result from this service when the console application will run

Comment: just tell me please how to call this type of service from Main() functio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 HttpWebRequest req = null;
 HttpWebResponse resp = null;
 string baseaddress = "http://deveqtradedb.lazard.com/API.aspx?action=export&entity=global";
req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseaddress);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding = UTF-8";
resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

1. Check Here

   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string url = "http://deveqtradedb.lazard.com/API.aspx?action=export&entity=global";
string response = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
```

Further readings:

1. [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)